# Create pagination using vuejs

Tags: vue.js, pagination, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I want like to build a pagination as the picture shows

[image]

However, I had looked through the internet but there is no other examples that can give me some idea on building it. The pagination is almost same like Google's one. But  i cant find any related to the vuetify.

```
<v-pagination
      v-model="page"
      :length="24"
      :withNextPrev="true" 
      nextText="Next" 
      prevText="Previous"
></v-pagination>

data() {
      return {
        page: 1,
      };
},
```

Comment: The code seems right. what issue are you facing?

Comment: Also, what Vuetify version you are using?

Comment: I'm using vuetify version 2

Comment: And what is the issue? The wrapping on multple lines? You can use a CSS override for the Flex container.